# Stubbing Backbone listenTo callbacks with sinon

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, sinon

I am trying to implement a simple test by stubbing the listenTo callback method of a Backbone.View.

However, it seems that I can't do this directly - I have to wrap the callback in an anonymous function. Any idea why this happens and how can I avoid the wrapper and still be able to stub the callback?

This does not work:

```
// MyView.js

var MyView = Backbone.View.Extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo('some:event', this.myFunc);
  },

  myFunc: function() {
    //.. do useful stuff
  }

});

// Trying to stub with sinon

var view = new MyView();
sinon.stub( view, 'myFunc' );

view.trigger('some:event');

view.myFunc.called; // is false;
```

However, this works:

```
// MyView.js

var MyView = Backbone.View.Extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo('some:event', function() { this.myFunc });
  },

  myFunc: function() {
    //.. do useful stuff
  }

});

// Trying to stub with sinon

var view = new MyView();
sinon.stub( view, 'myFunc' );

view.trigger('some:event');

view.myFunc.called; // is true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just stub the view's prototype before you create it:

```
sinon.stub(MyView.prototype, 'myFunc');
var view = new MyView();
view.trigger('some:event');

view.myFunc.called; // is true;
```

Sinon also has a [Util function](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#utils) called `createStubInstance`. However, I've never tried it so I don't know how well it works;

```
sinon.createStubInstance(MyView);
```

**Edit to address the comment (in fairly loose terms):**

Because of the way [prototypal inheritance works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and the way JS passes functions around by reference. When the view's instance is first created `myFunc` points to a reference of `MyView.prototype.myFunc`. This means that when the `initialize` function is called, the `listenTo` event handler is setup and it's using the reference that it has to `myFunc` at that time.

Stubbing the `myFunc` function after the view is created only changes the reference that view.myFunc points to (it changes to the new stub function reference rather than the `MyView.prototype.myFunc` reference). But this doesn't change the reference the `listenTo` is using.

One way to solve the problem is to do what you did:

```
this.listenTo('some:event', function() { this.myFunc() });
```

This solves the problem by pointing the `listenTo` to a reference an anonymous function that when run on the event trigger, will evaluate `myFunc` from the view at the time it is called, which will be the stub reference.

The other way to solve this is to stub the prototype function, so when the instance is created the reference of `myFunc` that is used by the `listenTo` is the stubbed function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, stubbing the prototype method does the trick. But, as a "noob", I'd like to know why stubbing the prototype method works and stubbing the instance method doesn't - do you have any idea?